# Problems with @InitBinder

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

i have a problem with  initBinder which i use in my form, is it allowed to do how below ?

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Class.class, "subClass",
                new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void setAsText(String text) {
                        setValue((text.equals("")) ? null : classDAO
                                .getClass(Integer.parseInt((String) text)));
                    }
                });

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Teacher.class, "teacher",
                new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void setAsText(String text) {
                        setValue((text.equals("")) ? null : teacherDAO
                                .getTeacher(Integer.parseInt((String) text)));
                    }
                });
    }
```

If i choose only one for example teacher it works perfectly but when I do this at the same time i get 400 request error.

Comment: Try switching the order of registration...

Comment: It worked but I don't know why was problem with orders is it has mind ?